# controls repeating in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On signup page I make communication preferences for each user, means how other person contact with that person for e.g: `"Phone","Email","Skype"` And on the settings page I am getting all the communication in the text_field. If user have 3 communication i.e `"Phone","Email","Skype".` Then It would show me like below:

```
Phone:   [1234567895]
Email:   [abc@ab.com]
Skype:   [abc       ]
```

assume `square brackets "[  ]" is text_field` but it show me below:

```
Phone:   [1234567895]
Email:   [          ]
Skype:   [          ]
Phone:   [          ]
Email:   [abc@ab.com]
Skype:   [          ]
Phone:   [          ]
Email:   [          ]
Skype:   [abc       ]
```

And below is my new .html.erb of setings page:

```
   <table>
    <% if @user_communication.blank? %>

        <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">

            Phone:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">

            <%= text_field :tf_phone, placeholder: 'Phone' %>

         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Email:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">

            <%= text_field :tf_email, placeholder: 'Email' %>

         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Skype:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">

            <%= text_field :tf_skype, placeholder: 'Skype' %>

         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Website:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">

            <%= text_field :tf_website, placeholder: 'Website' %>

         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Twitter:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">

            <%= text_field :tf_twitter, placeholder: 'Twitter'  %>
         </td>
      </tr>
    <%else %>
    <% @user_communication.each do |user_com| %>
    <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Phone:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            <% if user_com.CommunicationMode.to_s == "Phone" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :tf_phone, user_com.CommunicationDetail %>
            <% else %>
            <%= text_field :tf_phone, :placeholder => "Phone" %>
            <% end %>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Email:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            <% if user_com.CommunicationMode.to_s == "Email" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :tf_email, user_com.CommunicationDetail %>
            <% else %>
            <%= text_field :tf_email,:placeholder => "Email" %>
            <% end %>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Skype:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            <% if user_com.CommunicationMode.to_s == "Skype" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :tf_skype, user_com.CommunicationDetail %>
            <% else %>
            <%= text_field :tf_skype,:placeholder => "Skype" %>
            <% end %>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Website:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            <% if user_com.CommunicationMode.to_s == "Website" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :tf_website, user_com.CommunicationDetail %>
            <% else %>
            <%= text_field :tf_website,:placeholder => "Website" %>
            <% end %>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Twitter:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            <% if user_com.CommunicationMode.to_s == "Twitter" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :tf_twitter, user_com.CommunicationDetail%>
            <% else %>
            <%= text_field :tf_twitter, :placeholder => "Twitter" %>
            <% end %>
         </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <%end %>
</table>
```

Kindly suggest me where I make mistake, Waiting for you reply. Thanks.

Comment: I do not clearly understand your question: is it, how to take out the duplicated fields from your form?

Comment: I could not show me Phone, Email, Skype values of text_field at a time. At first time, it show me only Phone value in the text_field and other two text_field are blank, at second time, it show me only Email value in the text_field and other two text_field are blank and same as third time:

Comment: This Question is Unclear!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you're looping through `@user_communication` and inside the loop, you're showing all the communications.  Remove the loop and change the code to the following

```
<tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
  <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
    Phone:
  </td>
  <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
    <% phone = @user_communication.detect { |uc| uc.CommunicationMode.to_s == 'Phone' } %>
    <% if phone %>
      <%= text_field_tag :tf_phone, user_com.CommunicationDetail %>
    <% else %>
      <%= text_field :tf_phone, :placeholder => "Phone" %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then just repeat that for each communication.  Remember, don't place that code inside a loop.